# NullPointerException when adding Employee in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, nullpointerexception

I have a Hibernate Entity "Intranet" which has this code:

```
// Imports removed

@Entity
@Table(name = "intranets", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "company_name"))
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Intranet {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "INTRANET_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int intranetId;

    @Column(name = "owner_id")
    private int ownerId;

    @Column(name = "setup_done")
    private boolean isSetUp = false;

    @Column(name = "company_name")
    private String companyName;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "employees")
    @Column(name = "employee")
    private List<Integer> employeeIds;


    public int getIntranetId() {

        return intranetId;
    }

    public void setIntranetId(int intranetId) {

        this.intranetId = intranetId;
    }

    public boolean isSetUp() {

        return isSetUp;
    }

    public void setSetUp(boolean isSetUp) {

        this.isSetUp = isSetUp;
    }

    public String getCompanyName() {

        return companyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {

        this.companyName = companyName;
    }

    public int getOwnerId() {

        return ownerId;
    }

    public void setOwnerId(int ownerId) {

        this.ownerId = ownerId;
    }

    public List<Integer> getEmployeeIds() {

        return employeeIds;
    }

    public void setEmployeeIds(List<Integer> employeeIds) {

        this.employeeIds = employeeIds;
    }

    public void addEmployee(int id) {
        this.employeeIds.add(id);
    }

    public void removeEmployee(int id) {
        this.employeeIds.remove(new Integer(id));
    }
}
```

As you can see, I added two methods that don't directly are getters and setters but they're like convenience methods to have easy access to the collection and adding/removing employees.

When I call "addEmployee()" in my program, I am getting a simple NullPointerException. The question basically is **how I can initialize the collection to not have `null`** because I read that Hibernate uses internal implementations of collections and does not simply takes `ArrayList`.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Call `setEmployeeIds()` before `addEmployee()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `NullPointerException` because you have to initialize the list yourself. It does not matter which implementation you use. This will fix your problem:

```
@ElementCollection
@Column(name = "employee")
private List<Integer> employeeIds = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Ah cool, thank you. So the information about the internal implementations of Hibernate that differ from ArrayList and others is wrong? Or does Hibernate just set it to its implementation?

Comment: Well I don't know where you've read that but I don't think Hibernate needs any of the List implementations. I mean as long as we provide something that implements a List, hibernate will just use the functions that are in this interface. Doesn't matter what it really is behind the interface.